How to simplify $\int_0^x \lfloor \alpha+\beta t\rfloor-\lceil \alpha-\beta t\rceil \, dt$?
Is there any way of calculating or estimating
$$
I(x)=\int_0^x \lfloor \alpha+\beta t\rfloor-\lceil \alpha-\beta t\rceil \, dt
$$
for $\alpha,\beta>0$?
Some thoughts: For large $t$, one can write
$$
\lfloor \alpha+\beta t\rfloor-\lceil \alpha-\beta t\rceil\simeq 2\beta t
$$
thus
$$
I(x)\simeq \beta t^2
$$
However, I am wondering if it is possible to estimate it a bit further, even for small $t$. Any ideas?

It seems that $\lfloor \alpha+\beta t\rfloor-\lceil \alpha-\beta t\rceil = 2 \lfloor \beta t\rfloor$ for all $t$

@lhf that is not true.

With $F$ defined as $F(x)=\lfloor a+bx\rfloor-\lceil a-bx\rceil$ you can show that $f(x)=F(x)-2bx$ is periodic with period $P=2(a+b)$. Therefore it suffices to only focus on the integral $\int_0^z F(x)\mathrm dx$ with $|z|\leq 2(a+b)$. For values of $z$ outside this range you can correct it with as many multiples of $\int_0^P 2bx\mathrm dx$ as you need.
